multilinear polynomial in binary variables/indeterminate
I am not a mathematician or a computer scientist by training. Let us consider a setup of a binary vector of random variables of length n say $\vec{v}=(v_0,v_1,v_2....v_n)$ where each $v_i \in \{1,-1\}$. I would like to know if it is possible to write arbitrary polynomials $A(v): \{-1,1\}^n \mapsto [-\infty,\infty]$ as a multilinear expansion in these binary variables.
\begin{equation}
A(\vec{v}) = a_0 + \sum_i c_i v_i + \sum_{i,j, i\ne j} K_{ij} v_i v_j + \sum_{i,j,p, i\ne j\ne p} H_{ijp} v_i v_jv_p + .....\sum_{i,j,p,q.... i\ne j\ne p\ne q ....} G_{ijpq....k} v_i v_jv_pv_q....v_k
\end{equation}
where $a_0$, $\vec{c}$, $\vec{K}$, $\vec{H}$,...$\vec{G}$ are all defined over real field.
How to prove such a claim ? I am aware that monomials of real valued indeterminates like $,^2,^3, x^\alpha$ where $x \in \mathbb{R}$ are linearly independent and hence can span the space of a degree $\alpha$ polynomial by suitable linear combination. But in the equation above $v_i$, $v_iv_j$, $v_iv_jv_k$ etc are all binary valued monomials. I am not sure how to extend the result for such monomials and claim they can span the space for real-valued polynomials (and if extendable how to rationalize that). Any proof, proof sketch, references etc will be quite helpful
